# Which C standard header file defines NULL character?

Tags: c

Which C standard header file defines the symbolic constant for the `NULL` character (`\0`), which is the character used as string terminator?

While I have defined it myself in the program as:

```c
#define NULL_CHAR       '\0'
```

I am looking for an appropriate way to do so. Additionally, assuming it's defined in some header file, will there be a downside of including the header file just for the purpose of accessing this character against defining it myself?

Comment: there isn't one, just use '\0'

Comment: @dangee1705 Can you please add that as an answer?

Comment: i have added the answer

Comment: Note that the null byte `'\0'` (which is actually an integer constant in C, in contrast to C++) is separate from the standard name for the null pointer constant `NULL`.  ASCII uses the abbreviation `NUL` (one L) for code point zero aka `'\0'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `NULL` macro is defined in `<stddef.h>`. (It is also defined in several other headers.) It expands to a *null pointer constant* and is intended to be used with pointers, not with characters.

There is no standard macro for `'\0'`. It is equivalent to `0` (character constants have `int` type), and a macro for it would be of limited use.

The character `'\0'` is often referred to as a null character, but this is different from the `NULL` pointer constant.

Comment: Note that `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<string.h>`, `<time.h>` and `<wchar.h>` also define `NULL` — you seldom have to use `<stddef.h>` directly to obtain its definition.

Comment: As "An integer constant expression with the value 0", `'\0'` *is* a null pointer constant.  For that purpose, it can be used interchangeably with `0`, `NULL`, `(void *) 0`, and several other variations.  It's just that they are not all interchangeable for other purposes, such as setting a string terminator in a `char` array, and that the null character's *value*, appearing other than as an integer constant expression, is not equivalent to a null pointer.

Answer (score 5):

None. And `'\0'` isn't a `char` but `int`. If you don't want to use `'\0'` you can use `0`, `0x0`, `00`,  `000` and so forth...

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

> Which C standard header file defines NULL character?

None.  A *null character* is part of the language definition.

> A byte with all bits set to 0, called the *null character*, ... ; it
>   is used to terminate a character string.  C11dr §5.2.1 2

If you want your own macro, consider

```
#define NUL_CHAR ((char) '\0')
```

---

Note than when coded as `'\0'`, this is a constant of type `int`.

---

**`NULL`**

Uppercase `NULL` (with 2 `L`) is  used to name the *null pointer* constant `NULL`.  That is best used with pointers, not as a *null character* at the end of a string.

> The macro `NULL` is defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers) as a null pointer constant

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard definition of the null character. Just use `'\0'`

Answer (score 1):

There is no C standard library header that defines a null character constant. Instead, just use `'\0'` in your application.